# What is the difference between the ffmpeg vs lavaplayer on discord bot?

Tags: ffmpeg, discord

Im newbie and wants to develop a discord python bot, what is the best music player among these two? Can these two music player used on different server simulateously? Do ffmpeg support audio effects or an crossfade effect on the queues thank you so much I hope you can answer guys.

Answer (score 0):

for me the better engine for your music bot is lavaplayer if you want to operate at multiple instances simultaneously on different servers. It offers wide range of options and filters on the ffmpeg side it is a good option if you want to host it on a single server, a personal music bot. The advantage of ffmpeg is standalone compare to lavalink. For overall lavaplayer is much better for wider scale of operation.